# Why 'Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value'

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying use signed url to serve S3 bucket as private content via AWS cloudfront.

However I keep getting this error 'Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value'

```
<Error>
<Code>MissingKey</Code>
<Message>
Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value
</Message>
</Error>
```

Here is an example url

http://test.example.com/TestContent/test.html?Expires=1431195459&Signature=DSk8HwFScg6EFJla1p8UHB9EM28zXB7k5AwrXZjzByzdlTSMCG-md6MvUFT~pneaahfPbCcvxNWqZNYu5Dc1IE1JrjOhFP52APFsVmJDlPmqoQzOoCECclEsSvMpTPgva8L4TazDLtI6E5EuV632y76ZA8XoT2KHhzcj7ux9XhvQ6wyiiQxK9rb13sZJ~Cm~4qI-028dd6UkEIu1tUIM~SFh72wYjik7v8sfz2z5T5bZGZJrrfryO0zA9wpkabFA8JkrmfuBm55XWqcVk5OSOkrNn7iyuXwmrEeBJxufaiWE84UbfS8He12fh6~-seTr7UnOCtC4mBf4qlGsxCzKiw__&Key-Pair-Id=my-test-key

I have verified that I do not have any invalid characters ('+', '=', '/') in the signature.

And `Key-Pair-Id` is clearly present in the signed url.

My questions:

1) `my-test-key` is created using my IAM. Is it a problem?

2) Is it a must to provide a policy in a signed url?

3) Do I need to grant any permission to the object `TestContent/test.html` to the OAI?

**Edit**

If I change the Key-Pair-Id value to something else, I will get a different error message

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidKey</Code>
<Message>Unknown Key</Message>
</Error>
```

So apparently Key-Pair-Id is accepted by aws cloudfront.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use CloudFront specific key pairs.  More information on how to download or upload your own public key:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#KeyPairs

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I created an OAI, a new key pair was also created. What is this key pair for?

Comment: OAI's are used to authenticate your cloudfront distribution to your s3 bucket.  What you are trying to use is trusted signers, generating a new cloudfront key pair should have not modified your oai config.

Answer (score 3):

1) my-test-key should not be created under IAM. You need to login to the root account and go to "My Security Credentials" menu under your account-name. Expand "CloudFront Key Pairs" and create new one. Download Private Key file.

[image]

2) It is a must to include a policy in the url, but it should be encrypted. Refer to the section "Creating a Policy Statement for a Signed URL That Uses a Custom Policy".
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html

3) No, it shouldn't be granted for any public access. Just have a bucket policy so that your server url is allowed to request a get or any method.