# Struggling to reproduce and download flash video from a website using html script

Tags: javascript, flash, video

I have a flash video that I'm trying to download and no conventional flash video downloading software seems to do the trick.

I tried to get directly it from html script itself, like shown in this video tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waE3J0Jej_0

[image]

The script I found was :

```
<video controls="controls" style="max-width: 100%; display: block;" id="webinar_video" src="https://dpavupnx8si6b.cloudfront.net/ckeditor/attachment_files/data/000/000/086/original/beyond_20the_20basics-_20understanding_20the_20simple_20vs_20detailed_20piping_20option_20in_20xist-hd.mp4?Expires=1503537263&amp;Signature=Sb7SXPWaWa0Ul9Qr2BxliqUe0qy5cA7rYCo7c6x2uS1yxph~kCoKcd1ulu0u2VChXHP1WeiTEoJ~1bcCxFMFI-fuEkOeXYQrJ3PDKyxyxldQyMQ8dSf7nS1NfMoCrjXLawTKGDMyd9EYnj2~pye0C8P9Pj4jtoQUB0ry8JyuwKu5S-GIyHYN8aGH8OwVxNYXc~Lr2hpouY98sKzaDdfguRJhEatLs6yabnlY-l5HyzM4pt0vSyjt4qFTYk9yTnI9OEg617ddzgGg0d~DkPDhxcBVEVlx5nll4AfJrJOUzWzSv1x6bJ5LHpvwDH2xmEfLsmFdimioE5ibasJFYPryIA__&amp;Key-Pair-Id=APKAIQMXO5CQM37BVBXA"></video>
```

So I lifted this part:

https://dpavupnx8si6b.cloudfront.net/ckeditor/attachment_files/data/000/000/086/original/beyond_20the_20basics-_20understanding_20the_20simple_20vs_20detailed_20piping_20option_20in_20xist-hd.mp4

And pasted it on a new Chrome window But it did not work (see image below) :

```
<Error> 
    <Code> MissingKey </Code> 
    <Message> Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value </Message> 
</Error>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this content is private, so you must have the correct key pair to access it.

Take a look at this post for more information: [Why 'Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784539/why-missing-key-pair-id-query-parameter-or-cookie-value)