# cloudfront signed url Could not deserialize key data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

when i try to create signed url from cli it give me error
my command :
**aws cloudfront sign --url https://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/CDN.png --key-pair-id xxxxxxxxx --private-key private.pem --date-less-than 2022-08-25**
the output is
Could not deserialize key data.

Comment: Can you update to include the error message?

Comment: when i run the command this is the error message only "Could not deserialize key data."

Comment: Not sure but there might be some syntax errors... For example, did you use `file://...` for private.pem?

Comment: good add from you .. after i added the file:// give me another error 
**Password was not given but private key is encrypted**

Answer (score 0):

now after fixing the the command parametes its generate signed url but when i open the signed url it give me this error **

```
<Error>
<Code>MissingKey</Code>
<Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message>
</Error>
```

**

Comment: Try to check everything is done as should be. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784539/why-missing-key-pair-id-query-parameter-or-cookie-value/44646182) might help. By the way, you can write additional error in question, instead of answer like this.